# How to Create Parametric Survival Learner for MLR in R

Tags: mlr

I am following the instructions (https://mlr.mlr-org.com/articles/tutorial/create_learner.html) to create a parametric survival learner to use with MLR. My code is below.

When I try to make the MakeLearner(id = "AFT", "surv.parametric"), I get an error
dist is missing and no default is set even though I already specified the dist default in my code to be "weibull".

```
makeRLearner.surv.parametric = function() {
  makeRLearnerSurv(
    cl = "surv.parametric",
    package = "survival",
    par.set = makeParamSet(
      makeDiscreteLearnerParam(id = "dist", default = "weibull", 
                               values = c("weibull", "exponential", "lognormal", "loglogistic")),
    ),
    properties = c("numerics", "factors", "weights", "prob", "rcens"),
    name = "Parametric Survival Model",
    short.name = "Parametric",
    note = "This is created based on MLR3 surv.parametric learner"
  )
}

trainLearner.surv.parametric = function (.learner, .task, .subset, .weights = NULL, ...) 
{
  f    = getTaskFormula(.task)
  data = getTaskData(.task, subset = .subset)
  if (is.null(.weights)) {
    mod = survival::survreg(formula = f, data = data, ...)
  }
  else {
    mod = survival::survreg(formula = f, data = data, weights = .weights, ...)
  }
  mod
}

predictLearner.surv.parametric = function (.learner, .model, .newdata, ...) 
{
  survival::predict.survreg(.model$learner.model, newdata = .newdata, type = "response", ...)
}
```

Comment: You have a trailing comma in your call to makeParamSet

Comment: Please consider using `mlr3` and its extension package `mlr3proba` instead of `mlr`.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the trailing comma. I still have problem with the model where predict fails.  

mlr3 is much slower and results for my data are different than mlr.

Answer (score 0):

Based on [here](https://mlr.mlr-org.com/articles/tutorial/create_learner.html#survival-analysis), the prediction function needs to return linear predictors and that would be `lp` not `response`. Also, the `cindex` function of MLR does not seem to be consistent with the output of `SurvReg`. Based on [this](https://github.com/mlr-org/mlr/issues/2017) discussion, adding a minus seems to resolve the issue. So the prediction function would be as below.

```
predictLearner.surv.reg = function(.learner, .model, .newdata, ...) {
  -predict(.model$learner.model, newdata = .newdata, type = "lp", ...)
}
```